# Can I configure AppleScript to process a .pkg file when clicked, before installation starts?

Tags: macos, applescript, installation, pkgbuild, productbuild

I have a macOS Application that is packaged as `.pkg` file, and I want to run another apple script right after clicking `.pkg` file, but before installing the main application, I want to pre-process it with AppleScript. Is that possible?